# Subgradient of $(|x_1| + |x_2|)^2$

Tags: derivatives, optimization, convex-optimization, subgradient

Let $f(x) = (|x_1| + |x_2|)^2$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$

How do we find the subgradient $\partial f(x)$?

I tried to express $f(x)$ as $x_1^2 + x_2^2 + 2|x_1||x_2|$. I know how to handle the cases where neither of $x_1$ nor $x_2$ are 0,  but I'm not sure how to handle the cases where $x_1$ or $x_2$ are $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty straight forward. The subgradient of $|x|$ when $x\neq 0$ is $\text{sgn{x}}$, and $[-1,1]$ when $x=0$. Therefore $$ \partial\frac{1}{2}(|x_1|+|x_2|)^2 = \begin{cases} 
&x_i +\text{sgn}(x_i)|x_j|,  &x_i\neq 0 \\
&[-1, 1]|x_j|, &x_i = 0
\end{cases}  $$

**Additional comment**: I calculated this after unpacking the quadratic term, but notice that the chain rule would also work in this case. For the general case, let $h=f\circ g$. Assume $f$ is a nondecreasing convex function and $g$ is a convex function. Then for a point $x$, assuming that $f$ is differentiable at $g(x)$, the subdifferential $\partial h(x)=f'(g(x))\partial g(x)$. In your case, we may define $f(t)=\max\{t,0\}^2$ to get a nondecreasing convex function.

Comment: Should it be multiplied by 2?

Comment: @sedrick sure, I when quadratic functions are involved I automatically multiply them by $0.5$

Comment: What if $x_1=x_2=0$?

Comment: @daw then we have a singleton $(0,0)^T$ and the subdifferential is simply the gradient